# How to overwrite remote branch with different local branch with git

Tags: git

I have a remote branch that is the basis for a pullrequest.

I mainly worked on a different branch, however that should now replace the old branch.

I tried to do a `git push remote oldBranch -f` but that only pushes my latest local `oldBranch` to the git server instead of the current branch - no matter which branch i am currently on.

How can I replace the remote branch with my local branch?

EDIT:
If anybody else is interested, this is how i got this to work:

```
git checkout oldBranch
git branch -m 'oldBranchToBeReplaced'
git checkout newBranch
git branch -m oldBranch
git push myrepo oldBranch -f
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can use the `local-name:remote-name` syntax for git push:

```
git push origin newBranch:oldBranch
```

This pushes `newBranch`, but using the name `oldBranch` on origin.

Because `oldBranch` probably already exists, you have to force it:

```
git push origin +newBranch:oldBranch
```

(I prefer the `+` instead of `-f`, but `-f` will work, too)

To delete a branch on the remote side, push an "empty branch" like so:

```
git push origin :deleteMe
```

Comment: +1 good answer. Side note: the only difference between `+` and `--force` is when pushing multiple branches at the same time. `-f` will force all branches to whereas `+` will only force the refspec it's attached to, so I agree `+` is generally a better habit, although makes no difference when only pushing one branch and won't work if relying on the default push without a local branch name specified.

Comment: Tried SO many variations and this is only one that worked.